# Jsoncpp problem while building ethminer with cmake

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, ethereum, jsoncpp

Hi After some couple of days I've progressed with my attempt to mine ethereum this far:

First of all, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652841/boost-continually-fails-to-download-while-using-cmake-for-ethminer#) is my original post, where I got partial answers.

Following this tutorial: https://medium.com/coinmonks/eth-x-nvidia-x-ubuntu-1980393a36f8
I'm now stuck at `cmake --build .`

When I first ran it this error message showed up:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "jsoncpp" with any
  of the following names:

    jsoncppConfig.cmake
    jsoncpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "jsoncpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "jsoncpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "jsoncpp" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

After some googling I was able to find a solution which created file links `ln -s /usr/include/jsoncpp/json/ /usr/include/json`. This command takes care of the wrong include path inside the compile files.

However, now I'm getting a different message. I think it's a compile time error and I'm not even sure how to google this problem.

```
[ 56%] Building CXX object libethcore/CMakeFiles/ethcore.dir/EthashAux.cpp.o
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.cpp: In static member function ‘static dev::eth::Result dev::eth::EthashAux::eval(int, const h256&, uint64_t)’:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.cpp:28:29: error: ‘get_global_epoch_context’ is not a member of ‘ethash’
   28 |     auto& context = ethash::get_global_epoch_context(epoch);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.cpp:30:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘dev::FixedHash<32>::FixedHash(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   30 |     h256 mix{reinterpret_cast<byte*>(result.mix_hash.bytes), h256::ConstructFromPointer};
      |                                                                                        ^
In file included from /home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/Exceptions.h:31,
                 from /home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.h:21,
                 from /home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.cpp:18:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:136:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const string&) [with unsigned int N = 32; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
  136 |     explicit FixedHash(std::string const& _s)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:136:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:130:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const byte*, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromPointerType) [with unsigned int N = 32; byte = unsigned char]’
  130 |     explicit FixedHash(byte const* _bs, ConstructFromPointerType /*unused*/)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:130:14: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:112:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(dev::bytesConstRef, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromHashType) [with unsigned int N = 32; dev::bytesConstRef = dev::vector_ref<const unsigned char>]’
  112 |     explicit FixedHash(bytesConstRef _b, ConstructFromHashType _t = FailIfDifferent)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:112:14: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:94:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const bytes&, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromHashType) [with unsigned int N = 32; dev::bytes = std::vector<unsigned char>]’
   94 |     explicit FixedHash(bytes const& _b, ConstructFromHashType _t = FailIfDifferent)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:94:14: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:91:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(unsigned int) [with unsigned int N = 32]’
   91 |     explicit FixedHash(unsigned _u) { toBigEndian(_u, m_data); }
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:91:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:88:5: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const Arith&) [with unsigned int N = 32; dev::FixedHash<N>::Arith = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::unsigned_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >]’
   88 |     FixedHash(Arith const& _arith) { toBigEndian(_arith, m_data); }
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:88:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:79:14: note: candidate: ‘template<unsigned int M> dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const dev::FixedHash<M>&, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromHashType)’
   79 |     explicit FixedHash(FixedHash<M> const& _h, ConstructFromHashType _t = AlignLeft)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:79:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:75:5: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash() [with unsigned int N = 32]’
   75 |     FixedHash() { m_data.fill(0); }
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:75:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr dev::FixedHash<32>::FixedHash(const dev::FixedHash<32>&)’
   41 | class FixedHash
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr dev::FixedHash<32>::FixedHash(dev::FixedHash<32>&&)’
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.cpp:31:92: error: no matching function for call to ‘dev::FixedHash<32>::FixedHash(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   31 |     h256 final{reinterpret_cast<byte*>(result.final_hash.bytes), h256::ConstructFromPointer};
      |                                                                                            ^
In file included from /home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/Exceptions.h:31,
                 from /home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.h:21,
                 from /home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/EthashAux.cpp:18:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:136:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const string&) [with unsigned int N = 32; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
  136 |     explicit FixedHash(std::string const& _s)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:136:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:130:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const byte*, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromPointerType) [with unsigned int N = 32; byte = unsigned char]’
  130 |     explicit FixedHash(byte const* _bs, ConstructFromPointerType /*unused*/)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:130:14: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:112:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(dev::bytesConstRef, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromHashType) [with unsigned int N = 32; dev::bytesConstRef = dev::vector_ref<const unsigned char>]’
  112 |     explicit FixedHash(bytesConstRef _b, ConstructFromHashType _t = FailIfDifferent)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:112:14: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:94:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const bytes&, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromHashType) [with unsigned int N = 32; dev::bytes = std::vector<unsigned char>]’
   94 |     explicit FixedHash(bytes const& _b, ConstructFromHashType _t = FailIfDifferent)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:94:14: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:91:14: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(unsigned int) [with unsigned int N = 32]’
   91 |     explicit FixedHash(unsigned _u) { toBigEndian(_u, m_data); }
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:91:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:88:5: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const Arith&) [with unsigned int N = 32; dev::FixedHash<N>::Arith = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::unsigned_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void> >]’
   88 |     FixedHash(Arith const& _arith) { toBigEndian(_arith, m_data); }
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:88:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:79:14: note: candidate: ‘template<unsigned int M> dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash(const dev::FixedHash<M>&, dev::FixedHash<N>::ConstructFromHashType)’
   79 |     explicit FixedHash(FixedHash<M> const& _h, ConstructFromHashType _t = AlignLeft)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:79:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:75:5: note: candidate: ‘dev::FixedHash<N>::FixedHash() [with unsigned int N = 32]’
   75 |     FixedHash() { m_data.fill(0); }
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:75:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr dev::FixedHash<32>::FixedHash(const dev::FixedHash<32>&)’
   41 | class FixedHash
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr dev::FixedHash<32>::FixedHash(dev::FixedHash<32>&&)’
/home/luka/ethmining/ethminer/libethcore/../libdevcore/FixedHash.h:41:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
make[2]: *** [libethcore/CMakeFiles/ethcore.dir/build.make:63: libethcore/CMakeFiles/ethcore.dir/EthashAux.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:304: libethcore/CMakeFiles/ethcore.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
```

I also don't know how relevant these error messages are at the bottom.